# OpenLayers 2 set labels on a specific coordinates

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, openlayers

Hi im triying to print a group of labels on a map (OSM), the problem is that i don't know how to set those on a specific coordinates, the labels appear on the map but it is like i dont set the coordinates i attach the source.

```
var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Etiquetas", {
    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({'default':{
        strokeColor: "",
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWidth: 3,
        fillColor: "",
        fillOpacity: 0,
        pointRadius: 6,
        pointerEvents: "visiblePainted",            
        label : "${etiqueta}",

        fontColor: "${favColor}",
        fontSize: "10px",
        fontFamily: "Courier New, monospace",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        labelOutlineColor: "white",
        labelOutlineWidth: 3
    }},{ visibility: true, displayInLayerSwitcher: true })
});
var pointFeature;
var point;
for (i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
                var datos_ubicacion = elementos[i].split("|");
                if (datos_ubicacion[0] != "") {
                    var long = parseFloat(datos_ubicacion[7]);
                    var lati = parseFloat(datos_ubicacion[6]);
                    var coordenada = new OpenLayers.LonLat(long, 
lati).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'), 
map.getProjectionObject());

                    point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lati,long);
                    pointFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point);
                    pointFeature.attributes= 
                    {                                                       
                        etiqueta: datos_ubicacion[1],
                        favColor: 'black'
                    };                        

                }

            }     
            map.addLayer(vectorLayer);                  

        }
            vectorLayer.addFeatures([pointFeature]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved, just need to make a convertion of coordinates

```
var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(long,lati);
point = point.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'), 
map.getProjectionObject());
pointFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point);
```